# Jenkins pipeline retry happens even after timeout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am just starting with Jenkins pipeline.

This is the pipeline code I have tried to reproduce this potential issue:

```
node {
    timeout(time: 2, unit: 'SECONDS') {
        retry(2) {

            parallel(
                      a: {
                            build job: 'Child_Job', 
                            parameters: [
                                string(name: 'Param1', value: 'Val1'),
                                string(name: 'Param2', value: 'Val2')
                            ]
                         }
                    )
        }
    }   
}
```

Even after timeout of 2 seconds is over (which I thought would be timeout for attempts including retries), the second retry attempt happens anyways and the child job runs indefinitely.

This is the console log:

```
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] timeout
Timeout set to expire in 2 sec
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] retry
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [a] { (Branch: a)
[Pipeline] [a] build (Building Child_Job)
[a] Scheduling project: Child_Job
Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
[Pipeline] [a] }
[a] Failed in branch a
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
ERROR: Build of Child_Job was cancelled
Retrying
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] [a] { (Branch: a)
[Pipeline] [a] build (Building Child_Job)
[a] Scheduling project: Child_Job
Body did not finish within grace period; terminating with extreme prejudice
[Pipeline] [a] }
[a] Failed in branch a
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // retry
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Timeout has been exceeded
Finished: ABORTED
```

When I handle the exception of child job, this error (ERROR: Build of Child_Job was cancelled) is caught and handled. Retry does not happen in that case.

Even without parallel block, this is reproducible.

Is this a known issue or how it is supposed to work?

EDIT:

Please note that if I use sleep(time:3,unit:"SECONDS") instead of "build job" step, the retry attempt does not happen.
So, it could be something to do with retry block catching the child-job's cancelled exception (which is caused by timeout) and attempting a retry in-spite of it being inside a timeout block which has already timed out.

EDIT 2:

With the timeout block within retry block, the timeout is applicable for each attempt or retry separately. So if I set timeout as 2 seconds, 2 seconds is timeout for each time code block executes in retry block. I am actually looking to apply consolidated timeout for all attempts in retry block. 2 seconds as timeout for all attempts including retries. Of course 2 seconds as timeout is only for reproducing the issue.

Comment: It appears the `retry` is triggered because of the `timeout`. This seems correct given the scope of the code. The `parallel` also seems irrelevant to this behavior, so unsurprising that removing it does not affect it.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for your response. I was under the impression that timeout is for all code executions within the timeout block including all retry attempts. The main issue is that, the 2nd execution (retry) runs indefinitely. For example, one of the job I am trying to fix ran for 17 hours during business hours during a retry attempt, after initially timing out with timeout value configured as 3 hours.

Comment: Also, please note that if I simply have sleep(time:3,unit:"SECONDS") instead of "build job" step inside retry block, the retry attempt does not happen after timeout.

Comment: You probably need to enclose `timeout` within `retry` for that behavior. It seems coded the opposite of what you want at the moment.

Comment: Will give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: With the timeout within retry block, the timeout is applicable for each attempt or retry separately. So if I set timeout as 2 seconds, 2 seconds is timeout for each time code block executes in retry block.
I am actually looking to apply timeout for all attempts in retry block. 2 seconds as timeout for all attempts including retries.

Of course, I will have valid timeout value like in hours when using this functionality in  actual job. The 2 seconds is only for testing or reproducing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

This is just a workaround I have used to make sure the retry attempt within a timeout block is aborted, if it starts after the timeout duration is elapsed.

```
node {
    def previousStageDuration = 0
    def currentStageDuration = 0

    previousStageDuration = currentBuild.duration
    currentStageDuration = 0

        timeout(time: 2, unit: 'SECONDS') {
            retry(2) {
                currentStageDuration = currentBuild.duration - previousStageDuration
                // currentStageDuration is in milliseconds
                if(currentStageDuration/1000 >= 2)
                {
                    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                    error('Timed out. Ideally, the retry attempt should not have happened.')
                }

                parallel(
                          a: {

                            build job: 'Child_Job', 
                            parameters: [
                                string(name: 'Param1', value: 'Val1'),
                                string(name: 'Param2', value: 'Val2')
                            ]
                        )
            }
        }

}
```